# Font face according to language

Tags: php, html, css, fonts, font-face

**Case:**
I have question paper html in which my header , footer and some titles are in english language and questions, options and answer text will be in different language, english or hindi or marathi. All data comes from database. i have three font available freeserif, freeserifbold and mangal.

**Issue:** I want to apply freeserif font face for english content, freeserif bold font face for bold text and mangal font for non english content.
What i did is

```
@font-face {
        font-family: FreeSerif;
        src: url("<?= asset_url('fonts', 'FreeSerif.ttf'); ?>");
    }
    @font-face {
        font-family: FreeSerif;
        src: url("<?= asset_url('fonts', 'FreeSerifBold.ttf'); ?>");
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    @font-face {
        font-family: Mangal;
        src: url("<?= asset_url('fonts', 'mangal.ttf'); ?>");
    }
    body, html, font, * {padding: 0;margin: 0;font-family:"FreeSerif" !important;font-size:14px;}
```

but every time mangal font is override. i want use freeserif for english content and mangal for non english content.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: well you provide no info how you differ between the languages in your code. I assume you use classes for this. so you should be able to  make ".english{ font-family: FreeSerif;}" and ".marathi{ font-family: "Mangal";}  And ofc your should remove the !important for the font-family in your provided code. But as said, would be easier if you provide some more information of your HTML-DOM

Comment: I could not give class because content has not fixed language. actually i need to apply free serif for english content and mangal for non english content as i mentioned in my question.

Comment: You should not use classes to identify content in different languages, you should be using html `lang` attribute instead

Comment: Thansk @VilleKoo. but i have english and non english both type of content in my page and my last font is override everytime. that is the issue.

Comment: we need more code to provide an usefull answer. show us how the whole thing is built. My guess still would be that your !important overrides the rest

Answer (score 0):

You can target different languages in CSS if you are using correct language attributes in html (as you should)

```css
[lang="en"] {
  font-family: sans-serif
}

[lang="ne"] {
  font-family: serif;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p lang="en">this is english</p>
  <p lang="ne">and this is Nepali</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! but how can i identify the content language that is the issue :(

Comment: You can't magically detect different languages in css only. You need to provide that information in html, with language attribute, class or some other way